# how to set the layout of the 3 button to be horizontal in a row

Tags: android, button, layout

I would like to do the button layout in the following format.
I've tried relative layout,
I've tried linear layout, I've tried table layout, but it all fails me..

Can someone guide me?

[image: THIS IS WHAT IS WANT]

[image: This is what I get]

code:

```
 <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/updateBTN"
                style="@style/ButtonInside"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="100dp"
                android:text="Update" />
  <Button
                android:id="@+id/deleteBTN"
                style="@style/ButtonInside"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="100dp"
                android:text="Delete" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelBTN"
                style="@style/ButtonInside"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="100dp"
                android:text="Cancel" />

        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 3"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

gives this result:

[image]

Comment: what when it is at a larger screen, it will change? I mean move to one side?

Comment: No, it's proportional. It will stay anchored to the bottom and equally divided in 1/3rd, 1/3rd, 1/3rd (33%, 33%, 33%). You can try it by rotating your device (or emulator) and see that it will still fit properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:height:"match_parent"
  android:width:"match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:alignParentBottom ="true">
        <Button>
        <Button>
        <Button>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

linearlayout inside a relative layout will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a linearlayout with weightsum 90 and orientation horizontal and in it add three buttons with equal weights and ofcourse as per your image, you need to give each button a fixed width

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum=90>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Or give a fixed width to all of your buttons -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight=30/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Or give a fixed width to all of your buttons -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight=30/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Or give a fixed width to all of your buttons -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight=30/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to adjust width and height. This is the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.0"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />
    <LinearLayout/>
<RelativeLayout/>
```